# What is the use of Routing App Coverage File in iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, routes, app-store-connect

What is the use of uloading Routing App Coverage File in itunes connect for ios app? if i upload the file, i cannot use the app outside the gps boundaries mentioned in the geojson file? how this feature will work? Anybody know more about this?

Also, I have seen some app icon is showing at the bottom corner of the iphone lock screen when i reach any specific area(mall, airport etc). The app is related to that area. So to show that icon to users do we need to do anything specifically when we publish the app? sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

[In the apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html), it says

> Routing app coverage files are .geojson files which specify the
>   geographic regions supported by your app. The file can have only one
>   MultiPolygon element. MultiPolygon elements consist of at least one
>   Polygon. Polygons contain at least four coordinate points. Polygon
>   start and end coordinate points must be the same.

Comment: its about making geojson file :( hope u didn't get what i asked!!